# main': CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to pthread_create

Tags: c++, cmake, debian, pthreads, compiler-flags

I am building Faunus software using cmake with command -->

```
$cmake . -DENABLE_OPENMP=ON -DENABLE_PYTHON=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/user/localInstall/tstFaunusInstOpenMP -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/faunus-env/bin/python3.6 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/faunus-env/include/python3.6m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/faunus-env/lib -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-pthread"
```

I am getting build error like :

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/user/softwares/openMPfaunus-2.4.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_a43c8/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/softwares/openMPfaunus-2.4.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/user/softwares/openMPfaunus-2.4.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_a43c8
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_a43c8 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: in function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a43c8.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_a43c8] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/softwares/openMPfaunus-2.4.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_a43c8/fast] Error 2
```

File /home/user/softwares/openMPfaunus-2.4.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}
```

##############################################################

What I could understand from this is that there is section of file "CheckSymbolExists.c", which requires pthread_create. I wrote a simple code in C and ran using option: gcc example.c -lm -pthread and it's is working fine but if I run without -pthread option I am getting the same error concerning pthread_create.
Can someone help out this.

Comment: Of course it works if you add `-pthread` because `pthread` is required. So why would you omit it, if you already know the answer? And please format your posting properly.

Comment: You should probably talk to the maintainer of the software, to make sure that they correctly check for and use the pthread library in the configuration scripts.

Comment: You should check the CMakeLists.txt file(s) to see if there is an option which needs to be enabled in order to build with pthreads.

Comment: What help do you need exactly? You need to add `-pthread` to your compiler flags.

Comment: "I am getting build error like ..." - No, this is NOT the error you got. What you show use is **content** of the `CMakeError.log` **file**. The **error message** you got is **printed** by `cmake` executable. Exactly that message describes your problem and exactly that message we need for being able to help you.

Comment: @Devolus As I mentioned in my cmake options that I am adding -pthread but still the flag is not working. I have enabled the thread options in the **CMakeLists.txt** file as **set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)** and **find_package(Threads REQUIRED)** .

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, I would like to pass compiler flags. I am giving it as -**DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-pthread"** but it is not passing.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Error msg: The requested URL returned error:404
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/eigen-populate.dir/build.make:91: eigen-populate-prefix/src/eigen-populate-stamp/eigen-populate-download] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/eigen-populate.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:798 (message):
  Build step for eigen failed: 2
Call Stack (most recent call first): /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:889 (__FetchContent_directPopulate) CMakeLists.txt:207 (FetchContent_Populate)

Comment: You shouldn't pass it as compiler flags, but look if there is some support for it mentioned in the CMake files, which is quite different. Also `#ifndef pthread_create` looks wrong to me. I would have thought it should be the other way around `#ifdef pthread_create`.

Comment: So the error is `The requested URL returned error:404` and it is absolutely **unrelated** to pthreads. The error probably means, that address specified for FetchContent does not exist. You may fill a bugreport for the project you build.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are right.